# How to Check table row style.display = "table-row"

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have code to sorting table row and value *tablerowSUM*

**Problem** I want to collect *tablerowSUM* = "display: table-row" in console.log and show all
in outside function

and value *tablerowSUM* in my code it undefined

This my all code Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0s1uafgw/5/

```js
// =================================== Filter ======================================

var tablerowSUM; 

function filter(event, filterCol) {
  let element = event.target;
  let condt1 = document.getElementsByClassName(filterCol);
  for (let i = 0; i < condt1.length; i++) {
    if (condt1[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() == element.value.toLowerCase()) {
      if (element.checked == true) {
         condt1[i].parentElement.closest('tr').style = "display:table-row"
         
        tablerowSUM = condt1[i].parentElement.closest('tr');
         
      } else {
         condt1[i].parentElement.closest('tr').style = "display:none"
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(tablerowSUM)

document.querySelectorAll('.option1')
  .forEach(input => input.addEventListener('input', ()=>filter(event,"check1")));
```

```html
<div id="input">
  <label>Filter Name </label><br>
  <label>Human<input class="option1" type="checkbox" value="Human" checked/></label>
</div>


<table id="listingTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="check1">Human</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="check1">Robot</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="check1">Robot</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="check1">Robot</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="check1">Human</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="check1">Human</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Sorry for my bad English, can't explain all what I need, hope you understand what I need

Thanks !

Comment: `console.log(tablerowSUM)` must be after `filter(event,"check1")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't modify the variable tablerowSUM from within a function, it would be a side effect.

Use function properties like this

```
if (element.checked == true) {
     condt1[i].parentElement.closest('tr').style = "display:table-row"
     
    filter.tablerowSUM = condt1[i].parentElement.closest('tr');
```

and access it outside of the function like this

```
console.log(filter.tablerowSUM)
```

You don't need tablerowSUM declaration anywhere, it is now a property of the function.